# Create map for unrelated objects

Tags: trigger, after-trigger, nested

We have a object named Quote which is parent object in Lookup relationships with Quote Line object and Internal Calculation object.
On Quote Line object we have From Currency, To Currency and conversion rate fields and same fields are there on Internal Calculation object.
On After Update Trigger on Quote object, I want to copy the information of related Quote Lines record's of From Currency, To Currency and conversion rate field and create records of Internal calculation object but the records should be unique. That means if for a particular Quote, there are several quote line records which have from currency 'EUR', to currency 'USD', we only want one record and not several records where from currency is 'EUR' and to currency is 'USD'.

PFA the extract of Controller class:

```
public class CopyCurrencyConversion {
    
    public static void currencySorting(Map<Id, CameleonCPQ__QxQuoteLine__c> quoteLines)
    {
        Map<String,QxQuoteLine__c> quoteLineMap = new Map<String,QxQuoteLine__c>();
        String concatCur;
        Set<Id> quoteId = new Set<Id>();
        
        for(QxQuoteLine__c lines : quoteLines.values())
        {
            concatCur = lines.LI_Currency__c+lines.CurrencyIsoCode;
            quoteLineMap.put(concatCur,lines);
            quoteId.add(lines.CameleonCPQ__QuoteId__c);
        }
        
        system.debug('Valus of QuoteLine' +quoteLineMap.values());
        system.debug('KeySet of QuoteLine' +quoteLineMap.keySet());
        List<Internal_Calculation__c> intCalcList = [Select From_Currency__c, To_Currency__c, Conversion_Rate__c, Quote_Name__c FROM Internal_Calculation__c WHERE Quote_Name__c IN:quoteId];
        system.debug('Internal cal List: '+intCalcList);
        List<Internal_Calculation__c> updateList = new List<Internal_Calculation__c>();
        List<Internal_Calculation__c> insertList = new List<Internal_Calculation__c>();
        
        if(intCalcList.size()>0)
        {
            for(QxQuoteLine__c qlMap : quoteLineMap.values())
            {            
                for(Internal_Calculation__c intCalc : intCalcList)            
                {                
                    if(intCalc.From_Currency__c == qlMap.LI_Currency__c && intCalc.To_Currency__c == qlMap.CurrencyIsoCode && 
                       intCalc.Quote_Name__c == qlMap.CameleonCPQ__QuoteId__c)
                    {
                        intCalc.Conversion_Rate__c = qlMap.LI_Conversion_rate__c;
                        updateList.add(intCalc);
                    }
                    
                    else
                    {
                        Internal_Calculation__c intercal = new Internal_Calculation__c();
                        intercal.From_Currency__c = qlMap.LI_Currency__c;
                        intercal.To_Currency__c = qlMap.CurrencyIsoCode;
                        intercal.Conversion_Rate__c = qlMap.LI_Conversion_rate__c;
                        intercal.Quote_Name__c = qlMap.CameleonCPQ__QuoteId__c;
                        insertList.add(intercal);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        else
        {
            for(CameleonCPQ__QxQuoteLine__c qlMap : quoteLineMap.values())
            {
                Internal_Calculation__c intercal = new Internal_Calculation__c();
                intercal.From_Currency__c = qlMap.LI_Currency__c;
                intercal.To_Currency__c = qlMap.CurrencyIsoCode;
                intercal.Conversion_Rate__c = qlMap.LI_Conversion_rate__c;
                intercal.Quote_Name__c = qlMap.CameleonCPQ__QuoteId__c;
                insertList.add(intercal);
            }
        }
        system.debug('Update List: '+updateList);
        system.debug('Insert List: '+insertList);
        Update updateList;
        Insert insertList;        
    }

}
```

I know my logic inside nested loop is catastrophic and will lead to many unwanted record creation but I just couldn't think of perfect approach. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: if the Internal Calculation objects are stored in a `Set`, then you will achieve uniqueness for free.

Comment: As long as these objects implement `equals` and `hashCode` (which, if they are SObjects, you get for free).

Comment: @cropredy Can you please elaborate it a bit by modifying my code snippet?

Comment: Rahul -- take  a look at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_set_sobject.htm?search_text=equality to see if that inspires an approach - that is, use sets instead of lists